# How to send additional parameters from syslog to logstash like message or some addtional name

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I want to send additional parameters like message from syslog in omfwd format and also need to know what filter i can set on logstash to read this additional parameter Syslog configuration: ..... action(type="omfwd" Target="1.1.1.1" Port="1234" Protocol="tcp" newMessage = "abc")

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to configure your logstash input filter to listen on UDP 514 for Syslog traffic

```
   input {
        syslog {
            port       => 514
            type       => syslog
        }
    }
```

Then take a look at how to process Syslog messages:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html#_processing_syslog_messages